# React router won't work for ReactJS app version 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I just created a new ReactJS app using `npx create-react-app` I believe this uses React version 18 (correct me if wrong).

I'm trying to set up a router for this app but I'm not sure which one to use: `react-router-dom` or `react-router` ..or another one?

I went ahead and installed `npm -i react-router-dom`

Here is my app so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {} from 'react-router-dom'; //adding this line is giving me errors

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

..however adding `import {} from 'react-router-dom';` is giving me compile errors like:

> ```
> Compiled with problems:X
>
> ERROR in ../node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index.js 13:0-836
>
> export 'AbortedDeferredError' (reexported as 'AbortedDeferredError')
> was not found in 'react-router' (possible exports: Await, MemoryRouter
> ```

are there other modules I need to install? Or should I be using another router?

Comment: You should probably read [the react-router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial)  on how to set up routing in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot leave the import statement empty. You need to actually import something.

Generally, it works like this -

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
```

You can read the [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial) documentation to learn more about it.